# Creating Partial ViewControllers in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller

I need to create a partial view controller, and want to do it in SwiftUI, but being fairly new to SwiftUI I'm not sure if it's possible. Is it possible to create something like this in SwiftUI? Where the purple is a viewcontroller and the background is another view controller[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to create something like this in SwiftUI, but you would not generally use VC's.

Comment: I guess a view would suffice, not sure how I would go about making it slidable to dismiss though. Done this 100 times with UIKit but this SwiftUI is kicking my ass

Answer (score 1):

In swiftUI this is just two views.
Heres an example.
You could use UIViewControllers for the top and bottom view by using.
UIViewControllerRepresentable protocol

see docs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/uiviewcontrollerrepresentable

```
struct SplitView: View {

struct TopView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVGrid(columns:[GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 100, maximum: 150))] ) {
                ForEach(0..<100) { item in
                    Text("item: \(item)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BottomView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            LazyHGrid(rows: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 50, maximum: 100))] ) {
                ForEach(0..<100) { item in
                    Text("item: \(item)")
                }
            }.background(Color.purple)
        }
    }
}


var body: some View {
    
    GeometryReader { proxy in
        
        VStack {
            TopView()
                .frame(height: proxy.size.height * 2/3)
            BottomView()
                .frame(height: proxy.size.height * 1/3)
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I need it to present at that size on a button tap and also hide on a button tap, also with sliding down functionality